# how to link smartly the private javascript included into the manifest.json compiled by webpacker in Rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I tried to link private javascript code for jquery for my app in according to the way of Rails6. But, it has been not linked automaticaly like as Asset pilplene in Sprocket.

Actualy only application.js except other private js files on pacs directory is linked with "javascript_pack_tag 'application'" in the layout view. 
So, I can be available by linking manualy the private javascript codes compiled in public/packs directory into the layout view.

*install JQuery

yarn add jquery

*app/javascript/packs/application/click_test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Wellcome to the World');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    $(this).css('color', 'white');
  });
});
```

*config/webpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []
  .......
```

*config/webpack/development.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

*app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

*app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JqueryTest</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I changed code manualy as following, and jquery can work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JqueryTest</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="/packs/js/application/click_test-cc5b88be7c8ba2fc22b8.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
    </script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

*public/packs/manifest.json

```
{
  "aplication/click_test.js": "/packs/js/aplication/click_test-cc5b88be7c8ba2fc22b8.js",
  "aplication/click_test.js.map": "/packs/js/aplication/click_test-cc5b88be7c8ba2fc22b8.js.map",
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-678a934fafa8cabf4c10.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-678a934fafa8cabf4c10.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "aplication/click_test": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application/click_test-cc5b88be7c8ba2fc22b8.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/aplication/click_test-cc5b88be7c8ba2fc22b8.js.map"
      ]
    },
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-678a934fafa8cabf4c10.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-678a934fafa8cabf4c10.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In Rails6, I'd like to know the best way to link JQuery code smartly like sprocket automatically.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files in the new for Rails 6 `app/javascript/packs` directory are treated as packs' *entry point*. So you should put `click-test.js` in *(say)* `app/javascript/features` directory and add to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```js
import 'features/click-test'
```

By the way. When using Rails `turbolinks`, `jQuery` initialization code should be subscribed to `turbolinks:load` instead of `document:ready`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well with your help.
I understood correctly about the meaning of entry point 
And thanks for your advice about turbolinks:load.

But if I have multi private js files, I think that have to set the each import.
I hope in Rails that these are imported by one directory  path or  automaticaly into application.js near future like Splocket.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple `.js` files you should import each one line by line.

Comment: Maybe you should refactor these files in one `ES2015` *module*. Then you can handle it with `npm` and use its *exports* in `application.js`. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion which might be the best way currently I hope.